# How do I keep systemd from killing my tmux sessions?

Tags: arch-linux, tmux, systemd

I understand why systemd wants to kill my stuff when I log out.  I want to make an exception for tmux.  Here's what I've got so far:

/etc/logind.conf

```
[Login]
KillUserProcesses=no
```

.xinitrc

```
loginctl enable-linger $USER
```

And an alias...

```
$ alias tmux
tmux='systemd-run --scope --user tmux'
```

Various google searches have told me each of these should work on its own.  None ever has.  Is there some other setting I can use to preserve my tmux sessions?

Comment: How have you confirmed that it's indeed systemd killing the tmux process?

Comment: Nope, good question.  Do you have suggestions for how I'd do that?

Comment: [`stap kill.probe`](https://github.com/hilbix/tino/blob/master/howto/stap.md) can identify the source of a `kill`.  Output looks like: `kill 15 418881(tmux: server) from  systemd(12762)`

Answer (score 8):

[systemd is known to do this, it's by design](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490267/prevent-logoff-from-killing-tmux-session). You can also see in your logs (do `journalctl -xe`) how it terminates your process.

I just [posted the following answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1226480/59971), but I'm going to reproduce here because it will be an issue on more systemd-based distros:

It turns out systemd is terminating all of your user processes when your session ends, for example when you terminate your SSH login because you think that you're just going to re-attach later with tmux. ;)

To fix, do all of the following steps:

1. Make the following changes to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
KillUserProcesses=no
KillExcludeUsers=root YOUR_USER_NAME
```

... and restart systemd-logind with `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind`

2. Enable lingering for your account with:

```
loginctl enable-linger YOU_USER_NAME
```

I initially only had the lingering enabled and the `KillUserProcesses=no`, but my tmux still got killed. Only after I modified `KillExcludeUsers` (thanks to https://askubuntu.com/a/1097134/59971 ) could I continue my neural network training in peace.

Comment: confirmed on Arch.

Comment: `sudo loginctl enable-linger $USER` did the trick.  Thanks, as this was the important missing bit!  BTW there is no need to edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` as `tmux` is no more killed if started with `systemd-run --scope --user tmux`